# Use string variable from sheet in filename

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save an excel file into a pdf into a folder based on its 'Name' (a named variable that is a string), with a filename based on its 'Name' and 'AccountNumber' (a named variable that is numeric).

I can get it to save when I use the 'AccountNumber' variable in the filename but I keep getting errors when I add in the 'Name'. I have tried putting it in as: Range("Name") or Range("Name").Text (or .Value), Name, its cell position (D3) etc... But no luck! It's either an error or it works but there is just an empty space in the filename/folder name where it should be.

```
Sub SavePDF()

    Dim NewPath As String
    NewPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF Outputs\Leads - PDF Outputs\" & "\" & Name
    If Dir(NewPath) = "" Then MkDir NewPath

        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=NewPath & "\Report - " & Range("Name").Text & " " & Range("AccountNumber").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Based on these errors it seems that the problem is caused by the variable being a string - how do I convert it into a string if it doesn't already think it is one? OR how do I tell it to add in a string variable into a filename?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's always D3, then use `Range("D3").Text` - The way you are doing it implies that you have a named Range called "Name".

Comment: What error do you actually get?  What is the value in your "Name" range?  Does that value contain any characters that are not valid in filenames?  You also have a variable called `Name` - where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: You also use `"... PDF Outputs\" & "\" & Name`, which is equivalent to `" PDF Outputs\\" & Name`.  Why do you want that double back-slash?  (It probably won't hurt, I think the o/s will just treat it as a single back-slash, but it seems pointless to do it.)

Comment: Where it works, the empty space where the file name is, what's the formula/way you're getting it? What have you tried? Is the named range `Name` a single cell or multiple?

Comment: @YowE3K the error varies depending on what I use ... I  tried to assign the name in the sheet itself (its a single cell) ,’Name’ will vary depending what is in that cell

Comment: @braX unfortunately I have tried that and it just comes up as an error. I would like Name to be a range - is that a problem for a string variable? Does it needn’t to be multiple cells (it would be a few merged cells)

Comment: (a) Please confirm that you have a range name called "Name", and that it refers to cell D3 of "Sheet1" (b) What value is currently in that cell? (c) You have a **variable** (not a range name) in your program called `Name` - where do you declare it and where do you assign a value to it? (d) What error do you get when you run the **posted** code, with your **current** data?

Comment: (e) based on your last comment to @braX .. please confirm that the "Name" named range refers to `=Sheet1!$D$3` (not to multiple cells)